# Why does my four bit multiplier enter infinite loop when testbenching it?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, test-bench

My four bit multiplier described in the code below enters an infinite loop when I try to test it via a simulation in Vivado 2022.2. The implementation of the multiplier is "Shift-and-Add Multiplication". The test bench vhdl code is written correctly.

When I cancel the simulation, the application allows me to step in like a debugger, and it seems like the "while" loop runs infinitely, because N is not decremented.
I searched for answers and I also added the sensitivity list, and it still shows the same problem.

Do you have any ideas as to why the while does not stop and N is not decremented? Or if it is any other problem somewhere else?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity four_bit_multiplier is
  Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) );
end four_bit_multiplier;

architecture Behavioral of four_bit_multiplier is

component eight_bit_adder is
  Port (x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        c_in: in STD_LOGIC;
        c_out: out STD_LOGIC;
        sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) );
end component;


signal B : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal Q : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal A : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := x"00";
signal adder_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal c_out : STD_LOGIC;
signal N: integer := 4;

begin

p1: eight_bit_adder port map(B, A, '0', c_out, adder_out);

process(x, y, B, N, Q, adder_out)
begin

B <= "0000" & x;
Q <= "0000" & y;

while N > 0 loop
    if Q(0) = '1' then
        A <= adder_out;
    end if;
    
    B <= B(6 downto 0) & '0';
    Q <= '0' & Q(7 downto 1);
    N <= N - 1;
end loop;

result <= A;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You made the mistake that most VHDL beginners make at least a couple of times: believe that VHDL signals behave like variables do in most programming languages. Surprisingly they don't. When you assign a signal, like in `N <= N - 1`, its value does not change immediately and in the following instructions (except if it is a `wait` statement) its value is still the old one. As the next instruction, in your case, is `while N > 0 loop`, your loop is infinite. It's time to stop coding and go back to your VHDL book.

Comment: There are other issues with your code: 1) your process is sensitive to signals that it assigns (`B`, `N` and `Q`). This creates another type of infinite loop that you would discover if you could fix the first issue. Here again, to understand this you will need to understand the simulation semantics of VHDL, signal assignments, etc. Your VHDL book is your friend. 2) You use 2 non-standard packages (`STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`) instead of the standard `NUMERIC_STD` or `NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED`.

Comment: 3) You describe a multiplier that uses a single adder to compute all additions of partial products, but you don't use a clock, registers and the control logic that would properly sequence all this in time. Instead you create a combinatorial loop. As long as this is only for simulation (one of the possible uses of VHDL), it's fine if you solve the other issues. But if you want to map this in hardware things will probably not work anymore unless your target is one form of self-timed logic and your synthesizer is compatible with it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you have used a signal, when instead you should have used a variable. Because Signals only get updated when a process syspends, the signal `N` is never updated, and with an initial value of 4 it never goes to any other value. This will mean the condition:

```vhdl
while N > 0 loop
```

will always be true, because the value of N can never be updated to 3 via

```
N <= N-1;
```

There are other issues, all related to using signals and loops. If you fix the `N` problem, you will still have problems assigning multiple values to various signals, with each assignment simply overriding the previous assignment.

As @thebusybee points out, `While` loops in VHDL are generally not synthesisable. The code presented appears to be trying to write VHDL as a software programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that VHDL is a **description** language, not a **programming** language. It includes such features, though, but only for simulation.

Loops with `while` are generally not synthesizable. Instead, use a `for` loop.

Comment: Again, this claim that VHDL is not a programming language is totally wrong (search Internet for lists of programming languages and see). I am a bit worried that some of my students could be confused by this kind of statements that are mainly dictated by a very restricted view of VHDL and its use, or by a too literal interpretation of the VHDL acronym. Anyway, explaining the differences between signals and variables in the simulation semantics of the VHDL programming language would be much more useful to the OP, I think.

Comment: Moreover, with most synthesizers, `while` loops are exactly as synthesizable as `for` loops. It is not a matter of `while` or `for`. For the simplest synthesizers that unroll all loops, it is a matter of statically computable number of iterations or not. By the way, you can always turn a `while` loop into a `for` loop and conversely.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Concerning "programming", if I program a CPLD, I define its inner working. Well, one can name the used language a "programming" language. I will never do this, because the programmed definition is "just" a description of this inner working. The abstraction level does not matter here. VHDL has some features of programming languages that help describe the logic, but these are never executed by the described system. I do not count purely simulated test benches here. ...

Comment: ... The main problem with this term is the resulting mind set. It is far too easy to mix concepts. Especially for a teacher, this is important to tell. But this is not the place to discuss such things, unfortunately.

Comment: What you maybe miss is that **all** programming languages (except maybe assembly and machine languages) describe a processing as a sequence of operations on a **virtual** machine that does **not exist in hardware**. This virtual machine is more or less implicit but it is always there. In VHDL the LRM describes very accurately this virtual machine in terms of the underlying simulation semantics and each VHDL statement is defined by the effects it has on the state of the virtual machine, like in **all** programming languages like java, OCaml...

Comment: The fact that you are 100% focused on logic synthesis and resulting hardware, and that you consider simulation as a negligible feature is not universal at all. In many design and validation teams simulation is essential and they use all standard software development tools that others use for java or rust development (make, git, coverage analysis, unit tests, non-regression tests, self-documented code, etc.) Repeating that VHDL is not a programming language is just in complete contradiction with what people do with it in the real world. Same with SystemVerilog or SystemC.

Comment: Oh well. Why should a description language not use the model of a virtual machine? Some people call even HTML a programming language... I'm with you if we say that computer languages work on machines, many virtual. But even the LRM mentions "programming language" just once, in the reference to ADA. ;-) And the simulation part of VHDL is not the major part, even if the major part of _your_ work is simulation. Anyway, I have important things to do, have a nice day!